# Is a PHP resource immediately freed here or should I use sqlsrv_free_stmt?

Tags: php

Is a PHP resource immediately freed if there are no rows returned from a `sqlsrv_query` or after all rows of a resource are iterated through?

For example, in the following is the `sqlsrv_free_stmt($theRS);` statement actually doing anything or was the resource already automatically freed?

```
$theRS = sqlsrv_query(...xxx...)

if (!sqlsrv_has_rows($theRS)) {
    echo('No match');
}
else {
    while($theARR = sqlsrv_fetch_array($theRS)) {
        //code here
    }
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($theRS);   //Does this do anything or is the resource already freed at this point?
```

Comment: php won't auto-free if there's no more rows available, because php doesn't know if you'll be doing `rewind` or `seek`-type call to jump back into the result set. generally speaking, php will clean up for you when things go out of scope, and definitely will when the script exits. there's usually very little reason to have to clean up yourself, unless you're doing a very long-running script.

Comment: @MarcB That would have made a fine answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP doesn't immediately free the resource when it finishes iterating through a resource. It also doesn't immediately free the resource when the `sqlsrv_query` doesn't return any results.

For example, you can play around with this code and see what happens. Even though there are no ***results*** there is still a resource.

The first set of echos will show the resource between the arrows -->Resource shows up here<---. It also says this is a resource.

The second set of echos after freeing the resource show ---><--- and this is not a resource.

```
$theQUERY = "SELECT * FROM theTable 
    WHERE ID = '1' AND ID <> '1'"   //make sure it doesn't return anything
$theRS = sqlsrv_query($conn, $theQUERY)

echo('1 - before freeing theRS = -->' . $theRS . '<--<br>');

if (is_resource($theRS)) 
{
    echo('1 - this is a resource <br>');
}
else {
    echo('1 - this is not a resource <br>');
}

echo('<br>');
sqlsrv_free_stmt($theRS);

echo('2 - after freeing theRS =  -->' . $theRS . '<--<br>');

if (is_resource($theRS)) 
{
    echo('2 - this is a resource <br>');
}
else 
{
    echo('2 - this is not a resource <br>');
}
```